# How to take values from the class and use it in a def inside the same class Python/Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'inventory',
              'unit_price', 'price_with_tax', 'collection', 'images', 'price_after_the_first_tax']

price_with_tax = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
    method_name='calculate_tax')


def calculate_tax(self, product: Product):
    return product.unit_price * Decimal(0.1)
```

this is after add self variable

```
def second_calculate(self, order: OrderItem):
    return self.price_with_tax + Decimal(0.2)

price_after_the_first_tax = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
    method_name='second_calculate')
```

and also I face this error
AttributeError at /store/products/
'ProductSerializer' object has no attribute 'price_with_tax'

Answer (score 1):

The variable `self` is exactly what you need:

```
def second_calculate(self, order: OrderItem):
    return self.price_with_tax * Decimal(0.2)
```

It contains every variable/method that objects, which is instance of that class, can use.

Comment: thank you for your reply but it still error (AttributeError at /store/products/
'ProductSerializer' object has no attribute 'price_with_tax')

Comment: @amjad show how you have used it, please.

Comment: i upload screenshots Mr.Nexon and I am waiting for your answer

Comment: @amjad a bit too demanding, aren't we? ;) I don't see any pictures. Anyway, don't post code as pictures, make some effort before making demands.

Comment: i am sorry but it is the first time i ask question in stackoverflow, so i thought the photh is better but this the code again with the fix

Comment: class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):<br/>
    images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)<br/>
<br/>
    class Meta:<br/>
        model = Product<br/>
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'inventory',<br/>
                  'unit_price', 'price_with_tax', 'collection', 'images', 'price_after_the_first_tax']<br/>

    price_with_tax = serializers.SerializerMethodField(<br/>
        method_name='calculate_tax')<br/>

    def calculate_tax(self, product: Product):<br/>
        return product.unit_price * Decimal(0.1)<br/>

Comment: def second_calculate(self, order: OrderItem):   
        return self.price_with_tax + Decimal(0.2)   

    price_after_the_first_tax = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name='second_calculate')

Comment: @amjad don't put it in comments, edit your question and put it there.

Comment: Firstly I am very grateful for your help because I am a beginner now and secondly I have edited my question.  thanks!